# Mobile Browser Share Link Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, mobile, browser

I have a site where the urls have this structure:

`/item/:category`

`/item/item_detail/:id`

When on `/item/:category` clicking on the mobile share link, it sends the correct url (e.g. `/item/sports`). When on `/item/item_detail/:id`, it sends the same link as before (`/item/sports`).

To reiterate:

Browser url says: `../item/item_detail/12345`

The url that they get is: `/item/sports`

I have looked into the [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share), but I don't believe that fits my needs. The code is written in React, and is all client side (i.e. no server-side rendering). The routes are composed with `react-router-dom` and `react-redux`, so no atypical route setup.

What am I supposed to be looking for?

For context, I am referring to this mobile share function in mobile browsers:

[image: Mobile Share Link]

Answer (score 0):

For getting url you can use `window.location` object . In this object you will get all data related url, host and so on...

Comment: This does not help me.

Comment: Then you can use from props

Comment: Again, this does not help.